# Add a progressive surcharge based on countries in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, fee

Can I use a if statement and if so, how? Basically I want it to add 27 as surcharge to SE country and to all other countries 3 as surcharge.

Here is the original code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','wc_add_surcharge' ); 
function wc_add_surcharge() { 
global $woocommerce; 

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) 
return;

$county = array('US');
// change the $fee to set the surcharge to a value to suit
$fee = 27.00;

if ( in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ) ) : 
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $fee, true, 'standard' );  
endif;
}
```

Can I add:

```
if ( !county = 'SE')
$fee = 3
if ( county = 'SE')
$fee 27
```

?

Comment: `=` is an assignment, comparison is `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add many conditions to get different fee amounts, but as your countries are in an array, you will use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) php function instead of `==`.

There is a shorthand way when using `IF` / `ELSE` statements:

- The normal way:

  ```
  if ( 'SE' == $shipping_country )
      $fee = 27; // For Sweden
  else
      $fee = 3; // For others
  ```
- The shorthand way *(which makes the same)*:

  ```
  // The fee cost will be 27 for Sweden and 3 for other allowed countries
  $fee = 'SE' == $shipping_country ? 27 : 3;
  ```

Your code is a little outdated, so here is a revisited version including your conditions:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','wc_add_surcharge', 10, 1 ); 
function wc_add_surcharge( $cart ) { 
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) 
        return;

    $shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;

    // Defined fee amount based on countries
    $fee = 'SE' == $shipping_country ? 27 : 3;

    // Minimum cart subtotal
    $minimum = 300; 

    if ( $subtotal < $minimum ) { 
        $cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $fee, true );  
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: Perfect! And to add this only for order <300, this works?

`add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','wc_add_surcharge', 10, 1 ); 
function wc_add_surcharge( $cart ) { 
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) 
        return;

    // Allowed countries
    $countries = array( 'US', 'SE' );
    $minimum = 300;
    $fee = in_array('SE', $countries)  ? 27 :  3;

    if ( WC()->cart->total < $minimum ) {
    if ( in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), $countries ) && isset($fee)  ) { 
        $cart->add_fee( 'Fee', $fee, true );  
    }
}
}`

Comment: Thanks, is not working with the minimum order though :S Also I think there is a missing semicolon on the $subtotal row?

Comment: I tried it on two different websites (not in any way related not even themes/plugins). Didn't work. It's adding the surcharge no matter the amount.

Comment: Oh, and also only adding it to the arrays in this case US / SE. So all other countries it's not adding anything.

Comment: Thank you again, I really appreciate it. But it's still adding the surcharge even above 300 :S